# Error running Rails s app on OSX 10.9 Mavericks Bug Crash Report

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, terminal, ruby-on-rails-4, osx-mavericks

Running Rails 4 in OSX Mavericks

Created a new directory "code" and called `rails new app`, called `rails s` and everything worked great, then I `cd app` and tried `rails s` and get this crash:

```
evans-air:code evanewing$ cd app

evans-air:app evanewing$ rails s

/Users/evanewing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------

   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:

     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   the more detail of.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------

c:0033 p:-17542664622486 s:0098 e:000097 TOP    [FINISH]

c:0032 p:---- s:0096 e:000095 CFUNC  :require
c:0031 p:0009 s:0092 e:000091 CLASS  /Users/evanewing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:13
c:0030 p:0011 s:0090 e:000089 CLASS  /Users/evanewing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:12
```

#### this continues on with about 300 lines of similar code...towards the bottom:

```
-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: bin/rails

* Loaded features:

0 enumerator.so
1 /Users/evanewing/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/enc/encdb.bundle
2 /Users/evanewing/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/enc/trans/transdb.bundle

###

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score -1):

You can only call `rails s` from within the root directory of your rails app, not within the app directory.